# How come the the index action renders the show view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I've noticed that index actions(methods) in the controller typically render the show view.

So for example:

```
/posts/index
```

when on my `localhost` renders the show view. While the simple

```
/posts
```

renders the index. Why is this? I haven't been able to find anywhere that explains this?

I'm fairly new to rails, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/posts` maps to the route of `index` action.

`/posts/index` maps to the route of `show` action. You'll get an error saying `Cannot find a post with id=index.`

Routes generated for resource `posts` would be as follows:

```
     posts GET    /posts(.:format)                                              posts#index
           POST   /posts(.:format)                                              posts#create
new_post   GET    /posts/new(.:format)                                          posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                                     posts#edit
post      GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                                          posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                                          posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                                          posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                                          posts#destroy
```

Rails would match the path `/posts/index` to the one of show action i.e. `/posts/:id`.

Answer (score 1):

when adding in the routes

```
resources :your_controller
```

rails by default creates the main 7 methods [index,show,new,create,edit,update,delete).

Index and show both are get requests however index doesn't expect an id after you controllers name

as in your example /posts, however show expects an id after your controllers name because its route is like this

```
/posts/:id
```

so any parameter after "/posts/" rails interpret it as an id